# Xamarin forms listview add with slide function

Tags: listview, xamarin, slide, smoothing

I have created an app for my music station which adds the last played song to a listview. The listview will be updated when a song ends and a new song starts.
Now I was wondering if it's possible that the newly added song can be added with some kind of slide function. So, if a new song will be added, the row smoothly slides down upon the top of the previous songs. I have searched if the ListView has such function but unfortunally I cannot find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, listview usage is not very wide in Xamarin. But you can achieve this by creating custom Animations CustomRenderer.

[look how to make Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

[look how to make Animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/305485/how-to-do-animation-to-my-xamarin-listview-before.html)

Since Xamarin Forms is Cross-platform, there may be some shortcomings in the view. one of which is not the easy accessibility of the Animation feature.

Comment: Aah, the ViewCell. That one I was thinking about. Great, Thanks!